# what is the proper way of calling multiple services in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest

Suppose I have a service that allows users to give some points to the other user. So, to send some points to the specific user, it needs to know which account is going to send and which account is sending. Thus, I create another service responsible for finding an account by its id. Everything works fine, but I just wonder what the proper way or best practice of doing this is. I have 3 strategies on my mind.

Here is how it looks like:

1. Let the controller calls the account finding service and passes it to the sender service.

```java
    // a method in Controller class
    @RequestMapping("/transactions")
    public ResponseEntity<?> sendNuggerPoint(Long senderId, Long receiverId, Long amountOfNugger){
        Optional<Account> sender = accountService.getAccountById(senderId);
        Optional<Account> receiver = accountService.getAccountById(receiverId);
        if(sender.isPresent()&&receiver.isPresent()){
            try {
                transactionService.transferNuggerPointToAccount(sender.get(), receiver.get(), amountOfNugger);
            }
            catch(InsufficientNuggerPointException e){
                return new ResponseEntity<>(e.getMessage(),HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
            }
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
    // a method in Service class
    public void transferNuggerPointToAccount(Account senderAccount, Account receiverAccount,Long amountOfNugger) throws InsufficientNuggerPointException{ 
        // get both account yum yum nugger
        Long senderCurrentNugger = senderAccount.getNuggerPoint();
        Long receiverCurrentNugger = receiverAccount.getNuggerPoint();
        if(senderCurrentNugger < amountOfNugger) {
            // throw exception if sender nugger is insufficient
            throw new InsufficientNuggerPointException("Sorry, insufficeint nugger point.");
        }
        senderAccount.setNuggerPoint(senderCurrentNugger - amountOfNugger);
        receiverAccount.setNuggerPoint(receiverCurrentNugger + amountOfNugger);
    }
```

2. Just pass both sender and receiver Id through and let sender service calls account finding service.

```java
    // a method in Controller class
    @RequestMapping("/transactions")
    public ResponseEntity<?> sendNuggerPoint(Long senderId, Long receiverId, Long amountOfNugger){

        if(sender.isPresent()&&receiver.isPresent()){
            try {
                transactionService.transferNuggerPointToAccount(senderId, receiverId, amountOfNugger);
            }
            catch(InsufficientNuggerPointException e){
                return new ResponseEntity<>(e.getMessage(),HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
            }
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
    // a method in Service class
    public void transferNuggerPointToAccount(Long senderId, Long receiverId,Long amountOfNugger) throws InsufficientNuggerPointException{ 
        // get both account yum yum nugger
        Optional<Account> sender = accountService.getAccountById(senderId);
        Optional<Account> receiver = accountService.getAccountById(receiverId);
        if(sender.isPresent() && receiver.isPresent()){
            Long senderCurrentNugger = sender.get().getNuggerPoint();
            Long receiverCurrentNugger = receiver.get().getNuggerPoint();
            if(senderCurrentNugger < amountOfNugger) {
                // throw exception if sender nugger is insufficient
                throw new InsufficientNuggerPointException("Sorry, insufficeint nugger point.");
            }
            senderAccount.setNuggerPoint(senderCurrentNugger - amountOfNugger);
            receiverAccount.setNuggerPoint(receiverCurrentNugger + amountOfNugger);
        }
    }
```

3. Create another entity and let the user send all information within the request body

```java
    // a method in Controller class
    @RequestMapping("/transactions")
    public ResponseEntity<?> sendNuggerPoint(@RequestBody Transaction transaction){
        try {
            transactionService.transferNuggerPointToAccount(transaction.getSender(), transaction.getReceiver(), transaction.getAmoutOfNugger());
        }
        catch(InsufficientNuggerPointException e){
            return new ResponseEntity<>(e.getMessage(),HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
    // a method in Service class
    public void transferNuggerPointToAccount(Account senderAccount, Account receiverAccount,Long amountOfNugger) throws InsufficientNuggerPointException{ 
        // get both account yum yum nugger
        Long senderCurrentNugger = senderAccount.getNuggerPoint();
        Long receiverCurrentNugger = receiverAccount.getNuggerPoint();
        if(senderCurrentNugger < amountOfNugger) {
            // throw exception if sender nugger is insufficient
            throw new InsufficientNuggerPointException("Sorry, insufficeint nugger point.");
        }
        senderAccount.setNuggerPoint(senderCurrentNugger - amountOfNugger);
        receiverAccount.setNuggerPoint(receiverCurrentNugger + amountOfNugger);
    }
```